# Facebook profile picture is not working in ionic hybrid application on ios devices

Tags: iphone, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

Facebook graph API tells me I can get a profile picture of a user using

http://graph.facebook.com/100001225634061/picture?type=large

which works fine.

But If I used the same application in iOS devices this link is not working. For Hybrid applications, Graph url is not redirecting in iOS.

Any solution for this? Single solution should work on both the devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently where a Facebook profile picture wouldn't show up in my Ionic iOS app. I used a similar link you mentioned above.

Investigating the app in Safari showed an error saying:

`The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.`

Turns out, for security reasons you have to use `https` instead of `http` in your links. Changing the link like that solved the issue for me.